# Is Ruby a useful language going forward for programming for tablets?

Tags: android, ios, ruby, tablet

I hope this(these) question isn't too vague. I've been on and off again programming since highschool. I learned Pascal there, then C++, and finally some Java in college. Then didn't spend much more time programming. Obviously a lot has changed in the past 13 years, and besides Minecraft, it doesn't appear Java ended up being *quite* as important as they told us it would be back then. But I'm curious to start programming again and a lot of (slightly older articles) were touting Ruby. I was looking into Ruby but I'm a little confused by it. I read the wikipedia page and looked through some sites.

Being somewhat familiar with Java, Java gets compiled to bytecode and run on the JVM. Since all JVMs have to support the standard, if you made a, say, graphical-windowed program with Java/Swing, any JVM on a computer with windowed environment would run it.

Of course, neither Apple nor Android tablets support Java or have a JVM(although android is Java-like)

Is this sort of how Ruby works too? Is there a ruby "JVM"? I saw something about the MRI but this is only one specific ruby interpreter, correct? And there isn't a ruby interpreter on tablets, is that also correct? And there are many different ruby GUI toolkits like FXRuby, but would these work on multiple devices including tablets? When installing your program, do you need to include distributables to install along with your software so your program can run? And moreover I saw something like RubyMotion for developing for iOS, does this basically "recompile" your ruby program to objective-C so it will run on an iOS device? You obviously can't install a ruby interpreter on an iOS device without violating Apple's ToS...

I'd also like to start teaching my kids to program a little since it's so incredibly useful. I'm starting with Scratch but will Ruby be useful for tablet and portable device programming in the future? Or is it fairly limited to devices with a fuller featured operating system?

Sorry to pepper with so many questions. I hope this is an okay forum for that.

Comment: Android is mostly based on Java & XML, and thus you need to know them, to develop native android apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Kinda maybe, but probably not.

Long answer: Ruby doesn't have a common bytecode specification, but it does have a common *language* specification. In general, Ruby written for one runtime will run in any other runtime, but you can't just shuttle around some compiled Ruby bytecode between runtimes, since each runtime has its own bytecode. This means that in order to run Ruby programs, you have to distribute the source and the target platform needs to have an interpreter available for it.

There are a lot of runtimes that implement Ruby, such as MRI ("Matz' Ruby Interpreter", the canonical implementation), JRuby (which compiles Ruby to JVM bytecode), Rubinius (which uses LLVM to compile RBX bytecode to machine code just-in-time), and a number of others.

All that said, there's some work that's gone into making Ruby viable on more restricted platofrms. As you already found, you can target iOS devices with Ruby through [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/), which I believe basically compiles down to Obj-C - it's kind of like Coffeescript : Javascript :: RubyMotion : Objective-C.

[Ruboto](http://ruboto.org/) is an initiative to compile Ruby to Dalvik bytecode, but I haven't tried it so I can't personally say how well it works. You can also kind-of target Android devices through [Mirah](http://www.mirah.org/) (which isn't actually Ruby, just a Ruby-like language, by the creator of JRuby), which compiles to JVM bytecode. There are also initiatives such as [SL4A](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) which brings various scripting language runtimes to Android platforms, but they tend to be limited and only really useful as toys. The Android tooling is much more complete for Java, though, and it is really going to be less work to get an app written in Java running on Android than it would be to get an app written in Mirah running.

In the cases of RubyMotion, Ruboto, and Mirah, you don't have to distribute a runtime in order to actually run the code, since your distributable ends up being an Obj-C program or JVM bytecode jar.

As far as teaching goes, though, I'd probably suggest steering away from tablets as a primary vehicle for instruction, specifically because they are locked-down platforms that make it difficult for curious users to tinker with the innards. While it's really great to be able to write a basic program and see it running on the tablet, you as the app developer don't really have the kind of authority over the hardware that you would on a "normal" computing platform. Definitely include it as a part of the curriculum, but don't rely on it as the primary platform.

That said, Ruby and Python are both fantastic teaching languages, though, and can be used to teach a lot of the high-level fundamentals of programming. I particularly like Python for teaching (despite being a full-time Ruby developer), as it is more opinionated about how things should be done, which is useful for the beginner, since it leaves less room for ambiguity. Once you start getting into specific platforms such as tablets, though, it may be more wise to use the primary languages for those platforms, because the restrictions there put an additional barrier in place that has to be overcome before you can start actually being productive on those platforms, and at the end of the day, *how* you tell the computer what to do is a lot less important than knowing *what* to tell the computer, which your kids will learn just a a part of the journey of becoming programmers. Once you know the concepts, languages are just a tool to express those concepts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was looking into Python and it also looks like there's a pretty good book for kids too http://www.amazon.com/Python-Kids-Playful-Introduction-Programming/dp/1593274076 [br]I'll give it a shot. Reminds me a bit of the Logo turtle I had as a kid.